# Set complex key for Couchbase in java code

Tags: java, couchbase

I have a view and i can query from web console of couchbase like => `startkey=[36]&endkey=[36,{}]`
(My view has two keys, i want to filter by first key value.)

In my java code, i have tried with

```
ComplexKey rangeStart = ComplexKey.of(idcat, "{}"); 
            ComplexKey rangeEnd = ComplexKey.of(idcat); 
            query.setRange(ComplexKey.of(start), ComplexKey.of(end));
```

But i can not make query operates. It throws exception as below. If i remove the line of `query.setRange`, query returns result successfully.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to access the view
    at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.query(CouchbaseClient.java:789)
```

How can i set keys for this query?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what version of java SDK are you using?

Comment: I mean Couchbase Java SDK, aka java client

Comment: hi avsej, i am using couchbase client version 1.4.5